# Connect Java with Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect a Neteans Java project with Mysql database and i cannot establish a connection and i do not know what could possibly go wrong

My Java code:

```
private void setupLoginEventListener() {
        loginBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                rightFirstText = userName.getText();
                rightText = password.getPassword();
                if (rightFirstText.isEmpty() && rightText.length == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JavaApplication6.this, "All fields are required", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else if (rightText.length == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JavaApplication6.this, "Password is required", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                } else {

                    try {
                        conn = getDBConnection();
                        pst = conn.prepareStatement("select * from pdie where username =? and password=?");
                        pst.setString(1, rightFirstText);
                        pst.setString(2, new String(rightText));
                        rs = pst.executeQuery();
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JavaApplication6.this, "Login Successfull");
                        } 
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JavaApplication6.this, "Login Failed");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public Connection getDBConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3536/";
        String dbName = "projectdb";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String connectUserName = "root";
        String connectPassword = "";
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, connectUserName, connectPassword);
            System.out.println("CONNECTION ESTABLISHED.");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("CONNECTION COULD NOT BE ESTABLISHED.");
        }
        return con;
    }
```

any ideas?

it gives me an error for null pointer exception in this line

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement("select * from pdie where username =? and password=?");
```

Comment: Do you have the driver installed?

Comment: Most likely, `getDBConnection` returned `null` because an exception was caught.  Instead of printing `CONNECTION COULD NOT BE ESTABLISHED.`, print the exception message `e.getMessage()`, which should tell you what went wrong.

Comment: When you get an exception: 1. Don't just print an error message of your own devising. Print the exception. Otherwise debugging becomes a mere guessing game. 2. Don't just continue afterwards as though it hadn't happened. Code that depends on the success of code in a try block should be inside the try block. In this case you shouldn't catch those exceptions inside this method at all.

Comment: its the driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver how do i install it?

Comment: You put the MySQL Connector-J JAR file on your CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

type these lines

```
        st=con.createStatement();
        String sql="SELECT * FROM TAB";
        rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
```

and try to print a a field; to test quickly if the problem is in you prepared statement but probably it's in your conn object.

Comment: don't forget to declare st as a statement

Comment: A problem in the prepared statement does not cause an NPE.

Comment: Your comment makes even less sense than your answer. Using the same statement more than once won't cause an NPE either, so changing to a new statement can't fix it. He is getting an NPE *preparing* the statement. Read the question. The string literal isn't null, so `conn` is the only other thing that can possibly be null. Clearly `conn` is null because of prior ignored exceptions. See the discussion under the question.